# Qt popup grabMouse for all children

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to create a popup menu like control that contains custom widgets. I need to capture the mouse, but I need to have the children in the widget still get their mouse messages. It appears the `grabMouse` sends events only to the widget that grabbed the mouse, not its children.

The popup is simply a series of buttons (using a QGridLayout). The control should work that the user presses the right-mouse button, the popup appears, they move to an item and release the mouse button. Optimally it would work exactly like a QMenu popup but with custom widgets and a custom layout.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that simply specifying attribute `Qt::Popup` is enough to get the fundamental behaviour required.

Installing an event filter on all children is also necessary. All mouse events, enter/leave/hover events must be captured. QT has a defect with grabMouse so that won't work -- the filter must be used to get expected behaviour.

Comment: This is of course not a complete answer, since none of the standard controls, like AbstractButon, work as intended. Since they didn't initiate the mouseDown they will not click any buttons.